# What does "default" Signifies in an Interface?

Tags: java, interface

As we know that in an **Interface all methods should end with a semicolon**,
but i came across this example in [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).So how is it possible to **write the body** in method in an **Interface** and What does **Default keyword Signifies**.

```
public interface Animal {
        default public String identifyMyself() {
            return "I am an animal.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: read about default methods. It was added in Java 8

Comment: In my humble opinion, default methods in interfaces are a scaled down version of the devil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) are a new addition in [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html).

> Default methods enable new functionality to be added to the interfaces of libraries and ensure binary compatibility with code written for older versions of those interfaces.